# g++ vs gcc, linking problem with a static library (.a)

Tags: gcc, static, g++

I'm trying to link a static library (.a) file with a .o file which supposedly uses the symbols from the library. However, when using gcc - the normal linker error comes up, regardless of using the .a file as

gcc -L. a.c staticlib.a

However, the same command works with g++ flawlessly.

Why is this happening ?

I can see that the .c file is totally legal c ( and hence c++ ), but then why isn't gcc able to detect symbols in the the library ?

Tried finding the symbols in the library using objdump, was able to find closely resembling symbols, but not exact ones. e.g:

Got 
00000000000000b0 g     F .text  000000000000004e _*Z15PhttsFn_InitTTSPh*
for the symbol *PhttsFn_InitTTS*

Can someone please explain this phenomenon ? I've also checked the architecture the library file was compiled for, and it's the same as my architecture.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like your library was compiled as C++, hence the symbol names are "mangled", and the entry points are only accessible to C++ code.

Comment: "totally legal c ( and hence c++ )" C is not a subset of C++.

Comment: thanks for the answer Paul :) Mathepic, sorry - poor choice of words I see - now that I think about it some legal C code is illegal in C++, like void pointer assignment to a pointer of another kind, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ uses something called name mangling, in order for namespaces, overloaded function names, etc, to get unique symbols in the compiled object file.

Your C code refers to a symbol `PhttsFn_InitTTS` explicitly. Now if compiled as a C, it will produce that very symbol name. However, since C++ needs to deal with all these different variations of the same name (e.g. overloading, with different parameter lists), it creates a 'mangled' version encoding namespace, and parameter types. In your case it was mangled to `Z15PhttsFn_InitTTSPh`, basically saying no namespace and no parameters. (I reckon Z15 means 15 character name; followed by no parameter list).

Invoking GCC as `gcc` allows it to pick the file format itself, based on file extension (`.c` -> C, `.cc` or `.cpp`, etc -> C++). Invoking it as g++ forces C++ mode.

Your .a-file is obviously compiled using C++, as it exposed that mangled symbol.

Comment: nice - now that you mention mangling - I remember reading about it a short while ago in a whirlwind revision of C++, clearly didn't stick enough for me to debug this. Thanks a lot for answering so clearly !